# How to integrate multiple nodes setup in hypeledger explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am looking some solution for hyperledger explorer as I am trying to integrate with my fabric network which has 1 Orderer and 2 Org nodes.

I have successfully setup hyperledger explorer  with one node but I need for two nodes which can show the blocks and transaction on both nodes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to add node address in config.json file and enable gossip external endpoint on both nodes

> CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT

Comment: Can you give sample of config.json please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the issue was, that I didn't set up the anchor peers. I recommend going through the official documentation, but in case you need some general pointers, you should do it in the following way: in config.tx set up anchor peers for each organisation, use `configtxgen` after creating channels to update them with anchor peers, when you join all the standard peers to a channel, update it once again with the appropriate anchor peer using the `peer channel update` command.